# Create Bezier Curve in Objective C using Paul de Casteljau algorithm

Tags: objective-c, xcode, algorithm, bezier

I am trying to use Paul de Casteljau algorithm to draw Bezier Curve for my homework, but it seems it is not perfect, here are the codes

```html
- (void)recursive_bezier :(double)x1 :(double)y1
                         :(double)x2 :(double)y2
                         :(double)x3 :(double)y3
                         :(double)x4 :(double)y4
{

  count = count+1;
  // Calculate all the mid-points of the line segments
  //----------------------
  double x12   = (x1 + x2) / 2;
  double y12   = (y1 + y2) / 2;
  double x23   = (x2 + x3) / 2;
  double y23   = (y2 + y3) / 2;
  double x34   = (x3 + x4) / 2;
  double y34   = (y3 + y4) / 2;
  double x123  = (x12 + x23) / 2;
  double y123  = (y12 + y23) / 2;
  double x234  = (x23 + x34) / 2;
  double y234  = (y23 + y34) / 2;
  double x1234 = (x123 + x234) / 2;
  double y1234 = (y123 + y234) / 2;
  
  
  if(isFlat)
  {
    //    // Draw and stop
    //    //----------------------
    [self drawLine:x1 :y1 :x4 :y4];
    
  }
  else
  {
    // Continue subdivision
    //----------------------
    if (count == 5) {
      isFlat=true;
    }

    [self recursive_bezier:x1 :y1 :x12 :y12 :x123 :y123 :x1234 :y1234];
    [self recursive_bezier:x1234 :y1234 :x234 :y234 :x34 :y34 :x4 :y4];
    
    
  }
}

- (void)drawLine :(double)x1 :(double)y1
                 :(double)x4 :(double)y4{
  countDraw = countDraw+1;
  NSLog(@"============%d============",countDraw);
  NSLog(@"x1 = %f y1 = %f",x1, y1);
  NSLog(@"x4 = %f y4 = %f",x4, y4);
   
  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
  [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x1, y1)];
  
  [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x4, y4)];
  
  CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
  shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
  shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
  shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
  
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me why the right side not calculated and how to make the curve smooth?

ps : i got the algorithm on [Bezier Curve Algorithm](http://www.antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/index.html#toc0011)

Comment: as a programmer who only cares about writing code that does what it needs to do relatively well and efficiently, rather than "doing homework": does your homework *require* you to use recursion here? Because doing this with a `for` loop is far more efficient. (recursion wastes time and memory tracking the call stack, which is *entirely* unnecessary here)

Comment: This homework requires it to be recursive. :)

Comment: please inform you teacher that this is a terrible way to each recursion ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that once `isFlat` is set to true, any further segments won't be subdivided properly, even at the top level. This is because it is information related to a specific level of the recursive calls and not something global to the whole thing. If you step through the execution of the code this should be more clear.

A better way to do it is to declare `count` as an int parameter to `recursive_bezier` and pass 0 at the top level when you call it, and pass `count + 1` when you call it recursively. You can get rid of the `isFlat` variable and just test for `count >= 5`.

Comment: OMG! Perfect! I just forgot how recursive thing works, but thanks to this, all matters solved. Thanks dude!